# KitKat issue: device turns on when plugged in

Tags: battery, charging, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Yesterday I updated my Samsung S4 to 4.4.2 (I9500UBUFNA2 - Kernel 3.4.5-742022 18-Feb-2014) via Kies 3. If device is turned off then I plug in, picture of measuring battery image appears for 2 seconds and then disappears as usual, then instead of battery level image, phone turns on. Same behaviour when I turn it off while charging: phone turns on again. I think battery level image cannot load due to a Kernel problem. Any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: installed I9500XXUFNB3 (via ODIN)